# Problem with customizer setting with $id containing 'widget'

Tags: theme-customizer

I'm having a very weird problem with customizer add_setting function when using an ID containing the word 'widget' in the ID;

The changes doesn't apply, it's like 'widget' is a restricted word. However, there are other settings where the 'widget' word can be included normally.

What could be causing this?

The code:

```
function customize_register($wp_customize) {

$wp_customize->add_panel('design', array('capability' => 'edit_theme_options', 'title' => 'Design'));

$wp_customize->add_section('widget_design', array('title' => 'Widget Design', 'capability' => 'edit_theme_options', 'panel' => 'design'));

$wp_customize->add_setting('widget_padding', array('capability' => 'edit_theme_options', 'type' => 'theme_mod', 'default' => '20'));

$wp_customize->add_control(new WP_Customize_Control($wp_customize, 'widget_padding', array('label' => 'Widget Padding', 'section' => 'widget_design', 'setting' => 'widget_padding', 'type' => 'select', 'choices' => array('0' => '0px', '10' => '10px', '20' => '20px', '30' => '30px', '40' => '40px', '50' => '50px'))));

}
add_action('customize_register', 'customize_register');
```

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: Here's it: http://pastebin.com/b9UsufVa

Comment: Post your code inline please and not as a link to an external site. Second, if you swap the `widget` keyword to the back of the string instead of the front, does that help?

Comment: Updated my question with the code. Yes, It works when it's not in the start of the string.

Comment: Ok. I can't spot the code responsible, so I don't feel comfortable writing an answer, but you seem to have found the solution-- don't use `widget` at the front of the string.